# Написать функцию которая возвращает все ключи для 4-х типов коллекций std::unordered_map, std::map, QHash, QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите есть ли какой-то способ создать шаблонную функцию, которая возвращала бы все ключи для заданного значения для нескольких типов коллекций: `std::unordered_map`, `std::map`, `QHash`, `QMap` ?

Comment: Своя специализация шаблонной функции для каждой колеции...

Comment: @Chorkov спасибо, где можно посмотреть пример такого рода задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Решение для стандартных контейнеров:

```
template<typename Map, typename Value>
auto keysByValue_std(const Map& map, const Value& value)
{
    typedef typename Map::key_type Key;
    std::vector<Key> result;
    for( auto& pair : map )
        if( pair.second==value )
            result.push_back(pair.first);
    return result;
}
```

Решение для Qt-контейнеров.
Стандарнтное не подходит, поскольку по историческим причинам, begin/end в них переберают только значения, но не пары ключ-значение.

```
template<typename Map, typename Value>
auto keysByValue_qt(const Map& map, const Value& value)
{
    typedef typename Map::key_type Key;
    std::vector<Key> result;
    for( auto i= map.constKeyValueBegin();
         i!=map.constKeyValueEnd();
         ++i)
        if( (*i).second==value )
            result.push_back((*i).first);
    return result;
}
```

Теперь нужно перечислить все типы контейнеры, и написать шаблонную функцию, реализующею для этого типа контейнера:

```
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const std::map<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_std(map, value);
}
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const std::multimap<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_std(map, value);
}
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const std::unordered_map<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_std(map, value);
}
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const std::unordered_multimap<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_std(map, value);
}

template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const QMap<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_qt(map, value);
}
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const QMultiMap<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_qt(map, value);
}
template<typename ...T, typename Value>
auto keysByValue( const QHash<T...>& map, const Value& value )
{
    return keysByValue_qt(map, value);
}
```

тест:

```
template<typename Map>
void test(const Map& map)
{
    std::cout<<"test : " << typeid(map).name()<<std::endl;
    for( auto key : keysByValue(map, 4))
        std::cout<<key<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test( std::map          <int,int>{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} );
    test( std::multimap     <int,int>{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} );
    test( std::unordered_map<int,int>{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} );
    test( QMap              <int,int>{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} );
    test( QHash             <int,int>{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} );
}
```

Если все типы контейнеров перечислять не хочится, можно использовать технику [SFINAE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE), и поерделять к какой группе контейнеров относится контейнер, например, по наличию члена constKeyValueBegin.
(в C++20 можно вместо нее использовать концепты):

```
template< typename T>
struct is_qt_associative_container
{
private:
    template<typename T2>
    static auto SFINAE(T2 map) ->decltype(  map.constKeyValueBegin() );
    static void SFINAE(...);
    using iterator_type = decltype( SFINAE(std::declval<T>()) );
public:
    static constexpr bool value = ! std::is_same_v< void, iterator_type  >;
};

template< typename Map, typename Value>
auto keysByValue(const Map& map, const Value& value )
{
    if constexpr ( is_qt_associative_container<Map>::value )
        return keysByValue_qt(map,value);
    else
        return keysByValue_std(map,value);
}
```

Такое решение лучтше расширяется (не тербует заранее знать все типы контейнеров), но менее устойчиво к неверному употреблению. Т.е. если в качестве аргумента функции задать не ассоциативный контейнер, а что-то третье - то сообщения об ошибках будут многостраничны и нечитаемы. Поэтому, ИМХО решение со специализацией предпочтительнее.